# How to get database configuration properties like JDBC URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD from user [UI]

Tags: database, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring boot.

I want to get the JDBC String,Username,Password from user like from form.

I am already using one db for authentication and other stuff.

I wanted to make an application that map columns from one table to another table and copy all the rows from one table to other table. [This is separate database from what i have used already for authentication and all other stuff]

Comment: Frontend[UI] -->data --> Backend: Rest controllers(data) --> env.setProperties(data) --> instantiate bd repository with data